# Explanation in simpler english of "written premium"

Tags: meaning

I just received an email from an insurance company where the full amount wasn't paid. The answer was: "As a gesture of good will, we will write this outstanding premium this time." Does this mean, that they will pay the leftover price? I am not a native so I don't really understand this phrasing.

Comment: Don’t stress, being a native speaker doesn’t allow one to automatically speaking *Insurance-ese* either :) Yes, they are saying you failed to pay the complete premium, but as a favor they are forgiving the remaining amount owed. Though I find it a strange use of *write* even in an insurance context, where that word usually means “what the we are charging you” (externally, to you) or “expected revenues” (internally, for reporting). Here they seem to use it synonymously for “write off” (but again, even if they meant to type “write off”, I’d not expect that term in communications to a customer).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that clarifies it all! I was already assuming this but felt like "writing premium" was a very confusing term and googling the term didn't really make it any clearer. I guess Insurance-ese should be its own language, but sadly there is no universal standard yet I guess ;)